# code for find button in ext js with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

i am using ext js with ruby on rails.
i have grid and one description form on my screen and the description form. 
display the record which is selected in the grid.
i also have "find by id" button along with text box on the screen
and i want my description form to display the record having the ID given in the text box by the user before click on the find button.
can any one help me?
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the link [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Ext-JS/CombineExtuxformSearchFieldandphpscript.htm)